# How to pause a Java "for" loop in order to expect a "p:commandbutton" click event ton be triggered in order to continue with the loop?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I have a list of books `List<Book>`, which I retrieve from my database.

Imagine that the Book class looks like this:

```
public class Book {

private String title;
private int pages;

// CONSTRUCTORS
public Book() {
}

public Book(String title, int pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
}

// GETTERS & SETTERS
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public void setPages(int pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}
```

}

In my service `bookService` I write a method in which I loop through the List

```
List<Book> bookList;
```

and I check whether the number of pages is has a number or it is "0" zero. In case the value is "0" zero, I want to show a form/dialog asking the user to define the number of pages.

For that reason I have built a form in my XHTML, which looks like this:

```
<h:form id="BookPagesPromptForm">

    <p:dialog header="Define number of pages"
        widgetVar="BookPagesPromptDialogWidget" dynamic="true" modal="true"
        resizable="false" width="300px" height="150px" position="center,top"
        showHeader="true">

        <div>Title : #{bookService.getTitle()}</div><br />

        <div>Pages  <p:inputText value="#{bookService.newPagesValue}" /></div><br />

        <div><p:commandButton id="savePagesCommandButton" value="Save Pages Value" onclick="#{bookService.closeBookPagesForm()}" /></div>

    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

In my service I have the following method which I use to loop through my booList:

```
public class BookService {

// ...
// ... Code ...
// ...

private List<Book> bookList;
private IBookDAO bookDao;

// ...
// ... More Code ...
// ...

public void updateRecordsWithZeroPages() {
    for (Book bk : bookList) {

        if (bk.getPages() == 0) {

            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

            context.execute("PF('BookPagesPromptDialogWidget').show();");

            // Here I need to wait for user's input and as soon as the user
            // clicks
            // the "savePagesCommandButton" I want to update the record in
            // my
            // database.

            bookDao.update(bk);

        }
    }
}

public void closeBookPagesForm() {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    context.execute("PF('BookPagesPromptDialogWidget').hide();");

}
```

}

In my flow `book-flow.xml` I have defined my service (partial code):

```
<view-state id="bookList">
    <var name="bookService" class="com.stavros.BookService" />
</view-state>
```

The proble is that in my loop it does not stop when in the first record which has "0" zero pages, but it goes through all records and stops only when the loop is finished. As a consequence the form appears and asks the user about the last value from the loop.

In case you know how to make a "pause" in the loop and continue the loop only when the user click on the the "savePagesCommandButton" on the UI, please let me know.

Comment: You cannot communicate in a good/safe/easily way with the client while being in a server side method. You could try with some push mechanism and pausing a thread, waiting for some semaphore (which is **bad** design**)) but I'd advice against it... Better to rethink your solution. Gather all with 0 pages, prompt the client for confirmation or whatever and only then do the real executions

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje is absolutely correct however if you will achieve this using threading concept then also it will be not a good solution imagine all the cases what if books came from DB and all is having 0 pages in that case how many calls you have to do and how many update then your thread will work like pause run pause run and so on which i gues nobody wants better collect all book Id  with 0 pages and finally ask the user to input and have values in some list finally once you got all the values update your dao list.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Thank you very much for your answer. I was coming to the same conclusion, but I wanted to meke sure that there is no other way to do it.

Comment: @techipank: Thank you as well for your answer. As I said to Kukeltje, I was having the same opinion, but I still wanted to see whether there is something more I can do. The example you gave with the bookList which could contain records with "0" zero pages, was the scenario which convinced me the most. Thank you.

Comment: You're using some framework for transactions like Spring?